# Is the hard problem of consciousness a question about why a person, as an entity which can experience, exists?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, existence, david-chalmers

The [hard problem of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness) is stated as-
'why objective, mechanical processing can give rise to subjective experiences.'

If we assume the universe to be a Turing machine, it appears to me that we are basically asking why some of the bits on the tape of some Turing machine also come along with a subjective experience, evidence for which exists in at least one case, one's own.

So, it appears that we are asking why we, as entities with subjective experiences, exist.

Is this correct?

Comment: No. The question why we have qualia has nothing to do with the question why we exist. We could have existed without qualia, or something else could have existed with them. And we cannot assume that the universe is a Turing machine because Turing machines are abstractions that have neither physical properties nor qualia. It would have to be, at least, some physically realized enhancement of them with extra powers.

Comment: Well you could, in a bit different phrasing, say what you're saying and then say the question is nonsensical, but that would be assuming the conclusion.

Comment: @Conifold If the universe contains at least one Turing machine, doesn't that make it a Turing machine?

Comment: I think this is partially correct. When a person dies, we say they ceased to exist. What is the mitigating factor here... it is the permanent end of "subjective experience" If I cease to have any experience, I'm either asleep or dead.

Comment: If you're asking *how* the asking subject exists, the thing which doesn't exist without qualia, and in a sense only has qualia, then yes. The hard problem asks how qualia arise.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss I personally do not think that the question is nonsensical. Firstly, i have edited the question with a clarification that when I say why i exist, I mean why the entity which can experience, exists. This is a sensible question because the existence of my subjective experiences is not essential for the functioning of this abstract Turing Machine (TM). Yet, I am here, experiencing experiences. I can imagine another identical TM where there is no accompanied entity with subjective experiences. So, why there is an entity with subjective experiences associated with this TM?

Comment: @Conifold I have added clarification in the question. When I say why i exist, I mean why the entity which can experience, exists. Also, when I say that the universe is a Turing machine (TM), I mean that the universe can be modelled by a TM. That is, a TM can help predict results of experiments. Any physicality of the universe surely comes from the fact that there are conscious observers that can experience the bits of this TM as 'redness', 'heat' etc.

Comment: For physicalists, and many other realists, "physicality" of the universe does not come from any conscious observers and would be there without anybody experiencing it. And since Turing machines, as we construe them today, do not model qualia, some enhancement of them would still be needed. Even then, why (or rather how) something that can experience exists in a 'Turing machine' universe is a different question from why some of what exists in this universe experiences.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh the universe is a dishwasher? Also, a can opener. An oak tree. There is apparently no limit to what the universe "is"...

Comment: I suggest using a more philosophy centric link than wikipedia eg https://iep.utm.edu/hard-problem-of-conciousness/#SH1b Or
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/. That would remove some way out objections

Comment: @ScottRowe If you define an oak tree as a ten tons of wood, bark, etc. arranged in a certain away then the universe is not an oak tree. If you define as anything that produced acorns, then it is. Same with being a dishwasher. If being a dishwasher means being able to receive dishes and wash them with jets of water, and you allow someone from outside the universe (God, or someone in a parallel universe, say) to insert dishes into the universe (with the right velocity and so on), and open and close the doors of any and all dishwashing machines so that the dishes are washed, then likewise yes.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh I am pretty sure that statements of the form "X is a Y" are singular and exclusive. X is Y and only Y. So no, the universe is not 'a' dishwasher, Turing machine, or any other thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not asking why we exist. We could exist without consciousness, just as many people (excepting panpsychists) suppose rocks, water, teabags and so on exist without consciousness. The hard problem of consciousness is to explain how phenomenal consciousness (including qualia) comes about from, or is facilitated by, material processes in the brain.

Comment: Depends on if "we" refers to the body or to the subject of experience.

Comment: I agree with @AmeetSharma 's comment. By my own existence, I did not mean the existence of my physical state. I meant the existence of my sense of existence itself that I am experiencing, along with qualia and other things. So, you seem to be saying that the question is not as to why I (as this entity which has these subjective experiences) exist. The question is how it emerges from the physical world. But I am not so sure about that. Chalmers seems to be posing it as a why question rather than a how question. For eg. see Wikipedia or the definition I quoted in my question.

Comment: @prem with the greatest of respect, you should have made that clear in your question.